# Are "thank you for additional details" and "thank you for the additional details" phrases both correct?

Tags: expressions, nouns, articles

My questions are the following.
Should we use the definite article here?
Are both variants correct?
Can you please provide the corresponding grammar article where such information can be found? I checked different articles, but didn't find any information in this regard. Thank you!

Comment: For the first, I would consider "thank you for any additional details" if the object is to elicit more information.

Comment: Are you talking about something you say as part of a request for additional details, or something you say after you have received them?

Comment: This is a part I say after I received some additional details (whether those are the ones I needed or just some additional explanation of an issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the first sentence (without the determiner) *asks* for additional details. The second one (with the determiner) does indeed thank for receipt of details.

1. *You have provided me partial information. Thank you for additional details*.

It does sound rather odd/passive-aggressive, and one would not normally say it that way. You'd normally say something like *Please let me have (some) additional details*.

2. *I have received the revised information. Thank you for the additional details*.

This is correct English.